# MVC DropDownListFor selected value not being selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having some problems getting the selected value to work for a DropDownListFor.

The DropDownListFor is populated with a list of times:

```
// creates list of times for visit times select list
DateTime DateToday = DateTime.Today;
DateTime DateTimeStart = new DateTime(DateToday.Year, DateToday.Month, DateToday.Day, 8, 30, 0);
DateTime DateTimeEnd = new DateTime(DateToday.Year, DateToday.Month, DateToday.Day, 18, 0, 0);
List<SelectListItem> TimeFrom = new List<SelectListItem>();

while (DateTimeStart.TimeOfDay != DateTimeEnd.TimeOfDay)
{
    DateTimeStart = DateTimeStart.AddMinutes(30);
        TimeFrom.Add(new SelectListItem()
        {
        Selected = (DateTimeStart.TimeOfDay.ToString() == ViewBag.VbVisitTime),
        Text = DateTimeStart.ToString("HH:mm tt"),
        Value = DateTimeStart.TimeOfDay.ToString()
        });
}

model.TimeFromList = new SelectList(TimeFrom, "Value", "Text");
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VisitDetails.VisitDateTime, Model.TimeFromList, "Select Time...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The selected value is set when the time of day = ViewBag.VbVisitTime, when I debug the value of ViewBag.VbVisitTime does equal a value in the dropdown list and i've also displayed the value of ViewBag.VbVisitTime on the screen and matches a value in the dropdown list so not sure why it isn't selecting the value.

Comment: Perhaps the `model.VisitDetails.VisitDateTime` takes precedence as the selected value over `Selected = (DateTimeStart.TimeOfDay.ToString() == ViewBag.VbVisitTime)`.

Comment: Setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored by by the `DropDownListFor()` method. Model binding works by binding to the value of your property. You need to set the value of `VisitDateTime` to match one of the option values and that option will then be selected.

Comment: Thanks your comments helped me figure it out, i'll answer the question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments above helped me answer my own question, so thought i'd just post it in case it helps anyone else.

The `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` was indeed being ignored, so I instead created a new property in my model.

```
public TimeSpan? VisitTimeFrom { get; set; }
```

And then set the value of this in my controller

```
DateTime? visitTime = model.VisitDetails.VisitDate;
model.VisitDetails.VisitTimeFrom = visitTime.Value.TimeOfDay;
```

Then the dropdown list automatically selected the correct value for me

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VisitDetails.VisitTimeFrom, Model.TimeFromList, "Select Time...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```